# How to setup remote sharing and file transfers

Tags: networking

My sister lives a town away. Want to be able to see shared network folder and files on her machine and vice versa. Would then want to be able to transfer (large) files over to her. We're both running W7; she has an AT&T modem/router combo; I've got a Netgear dual-band gigabit router.

Can we configure our routers to allow this?

Comment: If one of you are running Windows then look here for [FREE FTP server software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_software) options you may be able to use. You'd probably need to configure your server side router for port forwarding and connect via dynamic DNS or else your public IP Address. Go to http://www.showmyip.gr/ to get what your public IP address is from a home use typical setup... This is what you'd need to have the side that will connect to it to connect to or else setup Dynamic DNS (e.g. [**NO IP**](http://www.noip.com/)).

Comment: Those are quick thoughts if Dropbox, Skydrive, or GoogleDrive won't work for the need.